# How to monitor disk activity?

Tags: hard-drive, performance, monitoring

How do I view my Disk Activity on Ubuntu? For example, How can I monitor what is being written and read from disk as well as the percentage of disk usage?

I am looking for an application similar to the Resource Monitor in Windows.

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/9428/how-can-i-monitor-hard-disk-load-on-linux

Answer (score 101):

You can use iotop. To install, open a terminal and execute the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install iotop
```

To use iotop, open a terminal and type the following command:

```
sudo iotop
```

iotop features real-time display of all disk activity and also displays the command responsible for the activity and the user behind the command just like Resource Monitor.

[Click here for more information.](http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/)

[image]

Also similar to resource monitor is htop in it's ability to identify and kill processes:

```
sudo apt-get install htop
```

and to run htop in monitor mode:

```
htop
```

or, for more features and permissions to fully debug and kill individual processes etc.:

```
sudo htop
```

[image]

Comment: you were asking for disk activity, not disk usage. This is the perfect answer to your question.

Comment: Can you make iotop not list a certain process like `peek` which is recording iotop's output into a .gif via `ffmpg`?

Comment: @user25 For disk use, you will need to use a different command: `df -h -t ext4` This prints in human readable format (`-h`) and assumes that you are using ext4 format (`-t ext4`).

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix `sudo iotop $(echo $(ps -A | grep -v ffmpeg | grep -v peek | awk '{print $1}') | sed 's/ / -p /g;s/PID//g')`

Comment: @mchid +1 for replying to comment, but I ended up using `-p ProcessID` of the suspect.

Comment: It's 2022. I want a GUI. Jumping numbers are not as useful as a simple chart.

Comment: I see in `htop` that "it was 7% busy and now it's 23%". It does not show me the information I need to decide if a faster hard drive for my workflow will help.

Answer (score 96):

You can use **htop**.

```
sudo apt install htop
```

Then open htop and configure it:
<kbd>F2</kbd> -> Columns -> Set IO_RATE (or IO_RATE_READ/IO_RATE_WRITE) -> <kbd>F10</kbd>

And you will see something like this:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This should be the answer to the question!

Comment: super. this is correct answer.

Comment: Your screen shot shows DISK R/W, but I don't see that in htop.  What's the difference between DISK R/W and IO_RATE, IO_RATE_READ/IO_RATE_WRITE?

Comment: `DISK R/W` appears when you choose `IO_RATE` column in setup . `IO_RATE` is a total I/O (read and write) in bytes per second.

Answer (score 37):

You can try *nmon*

```
sudo apt-get install nmon
```

Try:

```
nmon
```

Output Like below:

[image]

```
Press d = Disk | Press c = CPU Info |Press r = RAM info | Press q = to exit
```

Comment: one top to rule them all!  this is fantastic, thanks for sharing.  haven't seen it before

Answer (score 14):

You can use `dstat` program. To install it, simply execute the command in a terminal

```
sudo apt-get install dstat
```

Using the `dstat` command, you will get a complete real time CPU/Network/Disk-Activity monitoring view like this

```
mas@mas-laptop:~ > dstat 
You did not select any stats, using -cdngy by default.
----total-cpu-usage---- -dsk/total- -net/total- ---paging-- ---system--
usr sys idl wai hiq siq| read  writ| recv  send|  in   out | int   csw 
 15   5  76   4   0   0| 181k  177k|   0     0 |   0    61B|1651  3609 
  5   0  95   0   0   0|   0     0 | 162B 1064B|   0     0 | 500   994 
 15   4  77   4   0   0|   0   292k| 302B   52B|   0     0 | 687  1919 
  6   1  92   1   0   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 496  1089 
  5   1  94   1   0   1|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 422   919
  6   1  93   1   0   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 517  1181 
  9   2  89   1   0   1|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 494  1066
```

---

To only get the usage info for disk for load indicator upto most recent 15 mintues, use `dstat --disk --fs --load` command. A sample output is given below

```
$ dstat --disk --fs

-dsk/total- --filesystem- ---load-avg---
 read  writ|files  inodes| 1m   5m  15m 
 895k  186k|13728    100k|0.63 0.73 0.84
   0     0 |13728    100k|0.63 0.73 0.84
   0     0 |13728    100k|0.63 0.73 0.84
   0     0 |13728    100k|0.63 0.73 0.84
   0    12k|13728    100k|0.66 0.74 0.84
   0     0 |13728    100k|0.66 0.74 0.84
   0     0 |13728    100k|0.66 0.74 0.84
   0     0 |13728    100k|0.66 0.74 0.84
   0     0 |13728    100k|0.66 0.74 0.84^C
```

---

`dstat --help` has these info:

```
Usage: dstat [-afv] [options..] [delay [count]]
Versatile tool for generating system resource statistics

Dstat options:
  -c, --cpu              enable cpu stats
     -C 0,3,total           include cpu0, cpu3 and total
  -d, --disk             enable disk stats
     -D total,hda           include hda and total
  -g, --page             enable page stats
  -i, --int              enable interrupt stats
     -I 5,eth2              include int5 and interrupt used by eth2
  -l, --load             enable load stats
  -m, --mem              enable memory stats
  -n, --net              enable network stats
     -N eth1,total          include eth1 and total
  -p, --proc             enable process stats
  -r, --io               enable io stats (I/O requests completed)
  -s, --swap             enable swap stats
     -S swap1,total         include swap1 and total
  -t, --time             enable time/date output
  -T, --epoch            enable time counter (seconds since epoch)
  -y, --sys              enable system stats

  --aio                  enable aio stats
  --fs, --filesystem     enable fs stats
  --ipc                  enable ipc stats
  --lock                 enable lock stats
  --raw                  enable raw stats
  --socket               enable socket stats
  --tcp                  enable tcp stats
  --udp                  enable udp stats
  --unix                 enable unix stats
  --vm                   enable vm stats

  --plugin-name          enable plugins by plugin name (see manual)
  --list                 list all available plugins

  -a, --all              equals -cdngy (default)
  -f, --full             automatically expand -C, -D, -I, -N and -S lists
  -v, --vmstat           equals -pmgdsc -D total

  --float                force float values on screen
  --integer              force integer values on screen

  --bw, --blackonwhite   change colors for white background terminal
  --nocolor              disable colors (implies --noupdate)
  --noheaders            disable repetitive headers
  --noupdate             disable intermediate updates
  --output file          write CSV output to file

delay is the delay in seconds between each update (default: 1)
count is the number of updates to display before exiting (default: unlimited)
```

For more information about this tool, look visit below links:

[1) Dstat home page](http://dag.wiee.rs/home-made/dstat/)

[2) DiskPerformance Community Documentation Page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskPerformance)

Answer (score 3):

Install htop first `sudo apt install htop`

As answered above by RedEyed if you want to see read write in bytes/sec for individual processes go to *setup (F2)* --> Columns --> Available Columns --> Select IO_RATE (as shown in the image below)

[image]

But if you want an overall disk IO read write to be shown like this :

[image]

Go to setup (F2)--> Meters --> Available Meters -->Disk IO and enter add and select where do you want it to be Left/Right Column and you're done.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could try [Stacer](https://oguzhaninan.github.io/Stacer-Web)

```
sudo apt install stacer
```

It looks like a good option if you want/need a graphical interface. It has many other features.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPsAo.png)