# How to check the disk activity of my hard-drive?

Tags: hard-drive, disk

I had a problem in Windows 8 where my hard-drive activity was reaching 100% all the time and the system was very slow. Now I've switched to Ubuntu Gnome and want to check if this is still a problem on Ubuntu. Is there a way to check this?

I am not looking for how much space I have on my HDD! I know how to find CPU and RAM usage as well. I am looking to find out the disk activity of my drive. For example, using  Windows Task Manager it reports the disk activity as 0.04%. This is what I am looking for:

[image: Disk Activity on Windows]

Comment: command df -h will show

Comment: also **ls -s -h** will display it

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try to use `nmon` — a command line program. Install it by running:

```
sudo apt-get install nmon
```

Then run it as `nmon`. You would get the following screen:

[image: nmon mainscreen]

Since you want to view disk activity, you need to press <kbd>d</kbd> to toggle the statistics for it. Upon pressing <kbd>d</kbd>, you would be presented with the following screen which shows your disk activity:

[image: nmon disk activity]

Press <kbd>q</kbd> to exit the program.

---

[More information about this tool can be found at IBM developerWorks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-analyze_aix/).

Answer (score 3):

I use System Load Indicator for a GUI solution. which is in the [indicator-multiload package.](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=indicator-multiload&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) It's available in the Universe repository for all currently supported versions of Ubuntu and can be installed either through the software center or via the CLI with `sudo apt-get install indicator-multiload`

It is a system load monitor capable of displaying graphs for CPU, IOwait, ram, cache, and swap space use, plus disk and network traffic. It puts a display on the top menu bar that looks like this. [image: SLI]

Right clicking on it provides a drop down menu with live info regarding the following: CPU, Mem, Net, Swap, Load, and Disk as seen below:

[image]

Configuration is accomplished via the Preferences option on the same menu The colors are adjustable as well as the monitor width and update interval. Here's an example:

[image]

For CLI solutions see: [How to monitor disk activity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/276669/how-to-monitor-disk-activity)

Answer (score 0):

- System Monitor Utility will give the exact results of your cpu and RAM usage.
- Search for System Monitor in dash and run it.

  [image]

OR

Run this command on terminal to install and run `iotop` which shows the disk usage,

```
sudo apt-get install iotop && sudo iotop
```

Comment: Not looking for ram and cpu usage I know how to do this but it doesn't show you how much of the " hard-drive" is being used by Ubuntu

Comment: On the system monitor, move to fiesystem tab.

Comment: again that shows how much of space in the hardrive. I am looking at how much the hardrive is being used at a given time depending on the load. this is an example in windows 8   http://www.nextofwindows.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/DBCTaskman-Performances-tab.png it says "0.04%" is being used at that given time .

Comment: Run this command on terminal, `sudo apt-get install iotop && sudo iotop`